# Pycharm ideolog для scrapy

Tags: регулярные-выражения, pycharm, scrapy

Нужна помощь в настройке плагина ideolog в пайчарм для подсветки логов от scrapy. Гугления лично мне не дали вразумительных резултатов, вынужден спросить здесь.

Пример:

```
2020-03-12 11:36:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Scrapy 2.0.0 started (bot: yandex_market)
2020-03-12 11:36:07 [scrapy.utils.log] INFO: Versions: lxml 4.5.0.0, libxml2 2.9.10
```

Моё решение не работает :(

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} \[scrapy.+?\]`? Пример https://regex101.com/r/3CCB61/1

Comment: Пишет Log format not recognized

Answer (score 0):

Может кому-то помогу, после долгих ковыряний настроил вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
([^\[]+)\s\[([\w\.]+)\]\s([\w]+)\:(.+)
```